# Best way to have a count() -> Result<usize> function on an interator?

Tags: rust

I'd like to do something like this:

```
let count = self.line_current[self.line_current_pos..]
    .split(self.separator)
    .take(i_count)
    .map(|s|if s.is_empty() { Ok(()) } else { Err(s) })
    .count()?;
if count != i_count {
    Err("Unexpected newline")
} else {
    Ok(())
}
```

This is for a line-oriented parsing function which skips an expected amount of separators.

However the count() function on iterators consumes the iterator and does not work with std::ops::Try. Is there an elegant way to count the valid items but return an error immediately if one of the items does not match the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to parse strings of the form `"field1,field2,A,B,C"` - so there are some number of garbage fields at the beginning that you want to skip (2 in this case), but you also expect 3 tokens coming after it - if less than 3 fields are present, you want to error out.

The signature for such a function looks like so:

```
fn parse(line: &str, skip: usize, count: usize) -> Result<Vec<Token>, Error>
```

And in this case, we would call `parse("field1,field2,A,B,C", 2, 3)`.

So we start by splitting the string by `','`:

```
line.split(',')
```

We skip over `skip` fields:

```
    .skip(skip)
```

We try to parse each field

```
    .map(str::parse)
```

Now the elegant trick - append an element onto the end of the iterator that will cause an error if we ever reach it. We use `Iterator::chain` with `Some(T)` - `Some(T)` functions like an iterator of one element in this case.

```
    .chain(Some(Err(Error::NotEnoughTokens)))
```

Take however many elements we need

```
    .take(count)
```

Collect the whole thing into a `Result<Vec<Token>, Error>` - this just works! The error returned will be the first encountered, so any parsing errors first, then the `NotEnoughTokens` error.

```
    .collect()
```

The full code using this, including token parsing boilerplate, looks like this:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Token {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Error {
    NotEnoughTokens,
    InvalidToken,
}

impl FromStr for Token {
    type Err = Error;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        match s {
            "A" => Ok(Token::A),
            "B" => Ok(Token::B),
            "C" => Ok(Token::C),
            _ => Err(Error::InvalidToken),
        }
    }
}

fn parse(line: &str, skip: usize, count: usize) -> Result<Vec<Token>, Error> {
    line.split(',')
        .skip(skip)
        .map(str::parse)
        .chain(Some(Err(Error::NotEnoughTokens)))
        .take(count)
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", parse("A,B,C", 0, 2));           // Ok([A, B])
    println!("{:?}", parse("A,B,C", 0, 3));           // Ok([A, B, C])
    println!("{:?}", parse("A,B,C", 0, 4));           // Err(NotEnoughTokens)
    println!("{:?}", parse("A,B,C,D", 0, 4));         // Err(InvalidToken)

    println!("{:?}", parse("field1,B,C", 1, 2));      // Ok([B, C])
    println!("{:?}", parse("field1,field2,C", 2, 1)); // Ok([C])
    println!("{:?}", parse("field1,B,C", 2, 2));      // Err(NotEnoughTokens)
    println!("{:?}", parse("f1,f2,f3,A", 3, 1));      // Ok([A])
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is very in-depth. The obstacle with this approach is that I'm doing deserialization using serde. This is for a labview LVM parser. Since I know roughly what the format is going to look like, the parsing functions are driven by serde's deserializer. The parse_separator function is invoked in locations where I know the number of empty tabs that I expect. Otherwise things are generally tokenized, I convert the type (if necessary) from a string eg ints or floats, and then hand it off to Serde's visitor.

Context:
https://github.com/spease/labview/blob/master/src/lvm_format.rs

Comment: Note that the above context is slightly older than what I'm working with at the moment - my in-progress version of the code uses a position usize instead of splitting the string every time in parse_token and the other functions are adjusted appropriately.